# What is the best approach to render multiple React componenes

Tags: reactjs, redux

I wanna to create a following React/Redux app, and I'm looking for the best approach to handle this.

Let's start from main `App` container:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {open} = this.props;
        return open ? <Maximized/> : <Minimized/>;
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    open: getIsOpen(state)
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    {}
)(App);
```

Now it's easy - depends on the state I render only two containers. `Minimized` container is easy so let's skip it.

In `Maximized` container I want to display a different views(?).

```
class Maximized extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {view} = this.props;

        let content = null;
        if (view === 'DEFAULT') {
            content = <Component1/>
        } else if (view === 'COMPONENT2') {
            content = <Component2/>
        }

        return <div>
            {content}
            <Close/>
        </div>;
    };
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    view: getView(state)
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    {}
)(Maximized);
```

`view` is from state selector `getView` and is handled by the simple if, but now I have only two components to display, in the future I think this components can be **n**.

I think about router with the [MemoryRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/MemoryRouter) (I can't use URL), but I don't know is a good approach because of I must store current state in the local storage.

Maybe there is any pattern, good practice or tool for archive this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is kinda strange that you would have so many components using the same URL. With that being said, if you absolutely can't use URL, I guess you can create a file that import all your components, and export  an object acting as a map between your `view` value and your component class. Something like:

```
import ComponentA from './ComponentA';
import ComponentB from './ComponentB';    
import ComponentC from './ComponentC';

export default {
  'DEFAULT': ComponentA,
  'PROFILE': ComponentB,
  'CONTACT': ComponentC,
}
```

Then at your `App` container, you can probably do something like this:

```
import ComponentMap from './ComponentMap';
...
...
...
render() {
  const Component = ComponentMap[this.state.view];
  return <Component />;
}
```

[codesandbox for demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/xp4pm8qvnw)

EDIT:
The reason for putting all the mapping to components at separate file is to have a separation of concern. Using a traditional `switch` or `if` logic would require you to add at the very least 2 lines of code to your App container. In time, your App container could be very lengthy. If your App container also handle other things (not just mapping to components), then it would be not very pleasant to work with it.

By using separate file, your App container will not be filled with all the mappings concern. The separate file is also less verbose than using `switch` or `if`. Compare adding

```
'KEY': ComponentX,
```

to

```
case 'KEY': ComponentX; break;
```

Last but not least, using `switch` or `if` would result in O(n) time to get the component you are looking for, compared to O(1) time if you are using javascript object.

Comment: Ok, it's good example. I was told about URL, but I was suggested the [MemoryRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/MemoryRouter) and using router as well. What is your opinion about that approach?

Comment: I actually have never used MemoryRouter before so I can't comment much on that. Sorry @PiotrOlaszewski

Answer (score 1):

I have used a similar pattern a lot and I think it works well. One change is I would just clean up your conditional logic a bit. I would use a `switch` instead so that it's much easier and cleaner to handle **n** amount of components:

```
class Maximized extends React.Component {

    getView = () => {
        const {view} = this.props;
        switch(view) {
            case 'DEFAULT': {
                return <Component1/>
            }
            case 'COMPONENT2': {
                return <Component2/>
            }
            case 'COMPONENT3': {
                return <Component3/>
            }
            default: {
                return <Component1 />
            }
        }
    };

    render() {

        const content = this.getView();

        return <div>
            {content}
            <Close/>
        </div>;
    };
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    view: getView(state)
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    {}
)(Maximized);
```

Comment: Pretty nice! What do you think about encapsulate a map view into component in separate file, as said @Jackyef?

Comment: I don't like that approach as much because you will have to update that file each time you add a new component. And even then, you'll still need some sort of conditional logic like a switch, so really I don't see a benefit to having them exported from a different file.

Comment: I would argue that once the list gets long, having all the switch cases in one file wouldn't be pretty, which will makes the file less pleasant to work with. Remember that you also need to import the Component itself before adding it to a new switch case. That's an additional 4 lines of code for every new component, compared to 2 lines if you use separate file. I don't see how working with separate file is worse than working with a potentially very lengthy single file. And no, you don't need to use a conditional just to get the component you need, a simple object does it well, and at O(1) too.